# How to get depatment wise max salary as well as name of employee having it?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this.

[image]
I want to find the max salary department wise and the name of employee who has it.
I ran MySql query

```
select concat(First_name,' ',Last_name) as Name,max(SALARY) 
from Employee 
group by Department;
```

which gives result as shown below.

[image]

In which max(SALARY) is correct but Emplyoee name is wrong.How to get both correct?

Comment: you don't  find the time for post your code  or schema and asking to SO comunity of writing code for you   ... take a look at this  ..http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a correct solution:

```
SELECT concat(e.First_name, ' ', e.Last_name) as Name, e.SALARY
FROM Employee e
WHERE salary = (SELECT MAX(SALARY) FROM Employee e2 WHERE e2.Department = e.Department);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT concat(First_name,' ',Last_name) as Name,SALARY FROM Employee WHERE salary IN (SELECT MAX(SALARY) FROM Employee GROUP BY Department);
```

this will help you.

Comment: Be sure to mark this as the answer if this is what you needed.

Comment: This solution is not correct.  Someone in Department A could happen to have the maximum salary for Department B, but it may not be the max for Department A.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find out what the max salary is per department, and then find the employee(s) in that department who have that salary.

Use a CTE or a Correlated SubQuery.

```
With myCTE (dept, maxsalary)
as (
Select dept, max(salary) over (partition by dept) from EmployeeTable)
Select concat(e.firstname, e.lastname), e. salary
from EmployeeTable e where e.Dept = myCTE.dept and e.Salary = myCTE.salary
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only max

```
SELECT first_name,department,salary FROM Employees WHERE salary IN (SELECT max(salary)  From employees GROUP BY department)
```

If you want max and min

```
select department, first_name, salary from employees e1 where salary in ((select max(salary) from employees where department=e1.department),  (select min(salary) from employees where department=e1.department)) order by department
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.name,t.dept_id,temp.max
FROM employee as t 
JOIN (SELECT dept, MAX(salary) AS max
FROM employee
GROUP BY dept_id) as temp
on t.dept_id=temp.dept_id and t.salary=temp.max
```